# I need an algorithm to build roads

Tags: procedural-generation

I'm building a game (with TIC-80) for my 4yo daughter. Aim of the game collecting some items from the shops and delivering them to houses. I've built some levels by hand but I think that a need to find a way to generate them. I checked some maze-generating algorithms but they do not fit my needs. Can anybody give me any suggestions to generate levels like in the screenshot?

[image: Screenshot of game]

Comment: A simple screenshot isn't enough to infer the core features you want to be present in your levels. We can only guess they are grid-based. Do paths have a particular property (e.g. closed loops, must pass near key points)? Do they account for additional scenery objects, such as trees or similar? There are many PCG algorithms out there, maybe you can get inspired by similar questions here on GDSE and add more information later.

Comment: Indeed. There are many algorithms to generate road networks, but which one fits your particular game depends on what must-requirements and should-requirements you have for said road network. The screenshot you posted doesn't even tell us what your fundamental game mechanics are. Perhaps they are intuitive for your daughter as soon as she interacts with the game, but they are not obvious for an observer who only sees this still-image.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included information about which maze algorithms you tried and how they failed to generate adequate output.